# Get Linq.Expression's Body from a UnaryExpression C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I would like to extend and to an existing expression by adding to it.
So logically I want exp3:

```
exp1 = o => (((o.AuditDateTime > 10/04/2018 00:00:00) && (o.AuditDateTime < 18/04/2018 00:00:00)))
exp2 = o => (o.EventType == "X")
exp3 = o => (((o.AuditDateTime > 10/04/2018 00:00:00) && (o.AuditDateTime < 18/04/2018 00:00:00))) && (o.EventType == "X")
```

I have IQueryable instance with a defined where Expression already, something like:

```
{AuditJournalEntity[].Where(o => (((o.AuditDateTime > 10/04/2018 00:00:00) AndAlso (o.AuditDateTime < 18/04/2018 00:00:00))))}
```

So I can grab the actual where expression it self using Arguments array (Arguments[1]):

```
{o => (((o.AuditDateTime > 10/04/2018 00:00:00) AndAlso (o.AuditDateTime < 18/04/2018 00:00:00)))}
```

However, I don't know how to grab the expression body part of the UnaryExpression so that I can add to it later on. 
What I want is this part:

```
(((o.AuditDateTime > 10/04/2018 00:00:00) AndAlso (o.AuditDateTime < 18/04/2018 00:00:00)))
```

If in debug, it is able to give this part using something UnaryExpressionProxy instance but it's a private member I think so can't really use that.
Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) is very helpful with it's `Dump` method for examining `Expression` objects and seeing their properties. [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) has methods for doing this for querying. See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49928256/2557128) for another approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`UnaryExpression.Operand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.unaryexpression.operand(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

In your scenario, I guess you want to get the predicate lambda expression. Which for `IQueryable<T>` source is wrapped in `UnaryExpression` by [`Expression.Quote`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.quote(v=vs.110).aspx) method. So you can use something like this:

```
static LambdaExpression ExtractLambda(Expression source)
{
    while (source != null && source.NodeType == ExpressionType.Quote)
        source = ((UnaryExpression)source).Operand;
    return source as LambdaExpression;
}
```

Then you can get the body using the [`LambdaExpression.Body`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body(v=vs.110).aspx) property.